# Views: Computing user's age "on the fly"

Tags: views, entities, datetime

Is there a way to compute the age of a user *on the fly* in the "rewrite result" section of a date field?

I am trying to avoid computed field and having to use cron on that one. What I would like to achieve is having the age calculated and displayed on the fly in a date field (date of birth) included in a view.

Any and all input on this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you with the "on the fly" age calculation:

- [PHP calculate age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age)
- [Calculate age based on date of birth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521146/calculate-age-based-on-date-of-birth)

Then use the [Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module to implement it in your view. Or if you want to use the SQL method you could use the [Views Raw SQL](https://drupal.org/project/views_raw_sql) module.